# Creating a custom class in Java, is id reserved or can you use id in your own classes?

Tags: java, android

Can you or it is best practice to do the following?

```
public class MyClass {
    private int id;
    private String title;

    public MyClass(int id, String title) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mean having a variable called id, this is not reserved and you can use at will.

Comment: _"is id reserved"_ It's not a keyword if that's what you're asking

Comment: It is fine, but I would suggest that your classnames start with upper case. `MyClass` instead of `myClass`. It is just a convention thing.

Answer (score 3):

Is not reserved. The full list of reserved keywords is here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

Comment: That's a useful link, although I'd be inclined to add "operator" to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Java makes no reservation of `id`. `Object` does not contain an `id` field and thus you can use this name for your purposes. It's a common practice to use ids in custom classes, especially if you're sending data to a database. However, you might consider using a better description for the field (such as `personID` for a `Person` class).

Comment: Thanks that helps! so for a Make Class I will use makeID for example.

Answer (score 0):

No, `id` is not reserved and you can indeed include them in your own custom java 
classes. This is common for `SQLite` access classes for example.